# Что происходит в при передаче объекта сервера в слушатель?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

1) Что происходит, когда в listen одного сервера, передается другой?

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer();
var io = io.listen(server);
```

2) И когда передается, уже слушающий какой-либо порт?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3033);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Также интересует это в контексте сокетов.

Comment: RTFM http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server(srv:http#server,-opts:object)

Comment: Понятно, что присоединяется к переданному серверу. Но зачем?

Comment: Никто не ответит?